# Value not assigned to variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I don't know what I do wrong, but this code just doesn't work for me:

```
mode="-P"
select mmode in "default" "fast"; do
    case $mmode in
        default ) break;;
        fast ) mode="-T 2C -P" break;;
    esac
done

echo $mode
```

The output is always "-P".
Somebody please tell me where's the problem, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A missing `;` causes it.  Say:

```
fast ) mode="-T 2C -P"; break;;
```

Comment: Oh god I knew it will be a little thing like that :D Thank you for the very fast solution!

Comment: @kennyevo `;` is not a little thing.  It is a command separator :)

Comment: `var=value cmd` is correct but different from `var=value; cmd` : in the first case, `var` will only exist for `cmd`. It is very useful for things like `IFS=: read ...` or `LANG=C file ...`

Comment: @EdouardThiel You are talking about something _completely different_.

Comment: @devnull in what sense ?

Comment: @EdouardThiel It's __quite evident__ that a variable was not being set for a command here.  Wasn't it?